# Dynamic Dropdown in Excel VB Userform

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have created a dropdown ComboBox1 in user form. The data which needs to be populated in the dropdown in stored in sheet named 'RawData' in cell range AE3:AE16. Please help me with the code in User Initialize() sub in order to populate the dropdown with the data in the range.

I use ComBox1.List to populate the data, but in this instance, this cannot be used.

Comment: Can't believe it was so easy. I just entered the cell range in the Rowsource of the Drop Down properties. Thank you very much, Denis.